# css gradient image link not working

Tags: html, css

Hello friends i try to make gradient effect photo on the cover. but link is not working. 
When you click on the picture i want to be redirected to another page. 
This is my demo [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/LG2Gj/)

**HTML CODE:**

```
<div class="container">  
  <a href="www.facebook.com"><img src="http://lorempixel.com/1920/480/"> </a>
</div>
```

**CSS CODE:**

```
body {
  background: #000;
}

.container {
  max-width: 1920px;  
  background-image: -moz-linear-gradient(270deg, rgba(0, 0, 0, 0) 50%, rgba(0, 0, 0, 1) 95% );
  background-image: -webkit-linear-gradient(270deg, rgba(0, 0, 0, 0) 50%, rgba(0, 0, 0, 1) 95% );
  background-image: linear-gradient(to bottom, rgba(0, 0, 0, 0) 50%, rgba(0, 0, 0, 1) 95% );

}

img {
  max-width: 100%;
  position: relative;
  z-index: -1;

}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Wrap the link around the container:

```
<a href="www.facebook.com"><div class="container">  
    <img src="http://lorempixel.com/1920/480/" />
</div></a>
```

[**Working Fiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/jats_ptl/LG2Gj/1/)

Answer (score 0):

Another solution is to change the image's `z-index` to a positive number:

```
img {
  max-width: 100%;
  position: relative;
  z-index: 1;
}
```